# Using AWS Lambda to run Python script, how can I save data?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlite, aws-lambda

I have a script that gathers data from an API, and running this manually on my local machine I can save the data to a CSV or SQLite .db file.

If I put this on AWS lambda how can I store and retrieve data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

*You can* save data in an instance of a lambda function, only you don't really want to use it as permanent storage. Instead, you want to use a cloud service that specializes in storing data, which one will depend on your use case.

### Some background info

When using lambda you have to think about it as an ephemeral instance in which you only have access to the `/tmp` directory and can save up to 512MB ([see lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)). The data stored in the `/tmp` directory may be only available during the execution of the function, and there are no guarantees that any information you save there will be available in future executions.

### Considerations

That is why you should consider using other cloud services to store data, e.g. Simple Storage Service (S3) for storing files, RDS for relational databases, or DynamoDB as a NoSQL database solution.

There are many other options and it will all depend on the use case.

### Working solution

With python, it is very simple to store files in S3 using boto3. The code uses the library requests to do a GET request to google.com and saves the output to an S3 bucket. As an additional step, it also creates a signed URL that you can use to download the file

```
# lambda_function.py
import os
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import requests

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

# This environment variable is set via the serverless.yml configuration
bucket = os.environ['FILES_BUCKET']

def lambda_handler(event, conntext):
    # Make the API CALL
    response = requests.get('https://google.com')

    # Get the data you care and transform it to the desire format
    body = response.text

    # Save it to local storage
    tmp_file_path = "/tmp/website.html"
    with open(tmp_file_path, "w") as file:
        file.write(body)
    s3.Bucket(bucket).upload_file(tmp_file_path, 'website.html')

    # OPTIONAL: Generar signed URL to download the file
    url = client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Key': 'website.html'
        },
        ExpiresIn=604800 # 7 days
    )
    return url
```

### Deployment

To deploy the lambda function I highly recommend using a deployment tool like [Serverless](https://serverless.com) or [LambdaSharp](https://github.com/LambdaSharp/LambdaSharpTool). The following is a `serverless.yml` file for the serverless framework to package and deploy the code, it also creates the S3 bucket and sets the proper permissions to put objects and generate the signed url:

```
# serverless.yml
service: s3upload

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  versionFunctions: false
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 30

  # you can add statements to the Lambda function's IAM Role here
  iamRoleStatements: 
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:GetObject
      Resource:
        - Fn::Join: ["/", [Fn::GetAtt: [FilesBucket, Arn], "*"]]
        - Fn::GetAtt: [FilesBucket, Arn]

# Package information
package:
  artifact: package.zip

functions:
  s3upload-function:
    handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
    environment:
      FILES_BUCKET:
        Ref: FilesBucket
    events: 
      # THIS LAMBDA FUNCTION WILL BE TRIGGERED EVERY 10 MINUTES
      # CHECK OUT THE SERVERLESS DOCS FOR ALTERNATIVE WAYS TO 
      # TRIGGER THE FUNCTION
       - schedule:
           rate: rate(10 minutes)

# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
resources:
  Resources:
    FilesBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: true
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

Now package and deploy

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# deploy.sh
mkdir package
pip install -r requirements.txt --target=./package
cp lambda_function.py package/
$(cd package; zip -r ../package.zip .)
serverless deploy --verbose
```

### Conclusion

When you run lambda functions, you must think of them as stateless. If you want to save the state of your application, it is better to use other cloud services that are well suited for your use case. For storing CSVs, S3 is an ideal solution as it is a highly available storage system that is very easy to get started using python.

Answer (score 0):

with aws lambda you can use database like dynamo db which is not sql database and from there you can download csv file.

with lambda to dynamo bd integration is so easy lambda is serverless and dynamo db is nosql database.

so you can save data into dynamo db also you can use RDS(Mysql)  and use man other service but best way will be dynamo db.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with the information afterwards.

If you want to keep it in a file, then simply copy it to Amazon S3. It can store as much data as you like.

If you intend to query the information, you might choose to put it into a database instead. There are a number of different database options available, depending on your needs.

Comment: S3 is a good option even if you need to query your data by leveraging S3 Select. It’s an impressive and powerful way to treat S3 as a server-less database. Another option for S3 is AWS Athena.